# How do I get a .txt file in columns without using csv?

Tags: python, list, csv, line, multiple-columns

Preferably something like this, but converted into what people call "The Old Way". I'm trying to get 4 lists & 4 columns with headers.

What I have so far (I'm Python Illiterate even thought this has to be in Python).

Old Way:

```
print("        Student Report")
print("First   Last      DOB    Rank")
print("--------------------------------")
ReadFile = open("mytext.txt","r")

with ReadFile as f:
   [line.split() for line in f]
```

csv Way:

```
import csv
columns = [[] for _ in range(4)]  # 4 columns expected
with open('path', rb) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(col)
```

The question is how do I get this(refer to "Sample Report" below)put into a Proper list of 4 columns.

Thanks :)

There's about 30 or so fake students.

**Intended Outcome**

```
Sample Report:

             Student Report

First        Last       DOB        Rank

--------------------------------------------

Coreena      Delisio    8/7/1988   Freshman

William      Barnes     10/26/1987 Junior

Joseph       Mahan      9/18/1987  Senior

Susan        Bevly      9/13/1987  Senior

End of Report
```

**I found it out thanks to everyone's feedback and answers.**

*This is the code that gets me to this outcome.*

```
## Report's Title

print("             Student Report")

## List Headers

F = ('First')
L = ('Last')
Birth = ('DOB')
Grade = ('Rank')
print('{:10} {:13} {:11} {:4}'.format(F, L, Birth, Grade))
print("--------------------------------------------")
ReadFile = open("input_file.txt","r")

## List of Lists Turned Into Columns

for line in ReadFile:
   list = line.split(',')
   First = list[0]
   Last = list[1]
   DOB = list[2]
   Rank = list[3]
   print('{:10} {:10} {:14} {:10}'.format(First, Last, DOB, Rank)) ## Columns

## 2 Added Blank Lines to Show Cleanliness

print()
print()

## End of Report

print('End of Report')

ReadFile.close()
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I get 4 columns of 4 lists side by side with headers in Python pulling the data from a file.

Comment: sorry but what is wrong with your approach? I mean `[line.split() for line in f]` seems pretty good to me.

Comment: I added the edit of the .txt outcome I'm trying to get to. I just don't know how to get to that outcome. I can't seem to understand how to get to that outcome. Every time I research lists and columns, everyone uses csv.

Comment: Just copy it in your question, no need to link to external ressources.

Comment: @MSeifert My first time ever doing any of this but I got it to look like the outcome I need it to be but just can't get the code to do that when reading to from a file. It needs to read the file and be able to put each line in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert here you can print out a string while defining its padding and where it will justify to for you to represent the columns.

An example of how to do this is to first assign each string to a value like:

```
for lines in open('mytxt.txt'):
    first = lines.split()[0]
    last = lines.split()[1]
    DOB = lines.split()[2]
    rank = lines.split()[3]
```

Next you can print them out while defining how many characters can be printed in the first column (works best for floating numbers), and how far are the columns from each other by:

```
    print('{:20} {:20} {:20} {:20}'.format(first, last, DOB, rank))
```

I have decided to limit the characters that can be printed to 20 per column (that would be your padding as well). You can also center, right, or left justify them using:

```
##center_justify --> print('{:^20}'.format(center))
##right_justify -->  print('{:>20}'.format(right))
##left_justify -->   print('{:<20}'.format(left))
```

Comment: I can't seem to get a list out it though. As per the example provided.

Comment: You worked this out alright? What was you problem with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
padding = 5
n_columns = 4
columns = [['a','bc3','c','de'],['sadasd','sad','a','a'],['123123'],['123']]
max_entry_widths = [max(len(entry) for entry in column)
                    for column in columns]
column_widths = [width+padding for width in max_entry_widths]
n_rows = max(len(column) for column in columns)

row_str = ("{{: <{}}}" * n_columns).format(*column_widths)

rows = []
for row in range(n_rows):
    entries = []
    for col in range(n_columns):
        try:
            entries.append(columns[col][row])
        except IndexError:
            entries.append("")
    rows.append(row_str.format(*entries))

print('\n'.join(rows))

# a       sadasd     123123     123
# bc3     sad
# c       a
# de      a
```

Comment: That is what I'm trying to get to thank you, but I'm trying to create column's from the data pulled from the .txt @BallpointBen and put into what you just created.

Comment: Lol I was a little confused